# Unable to use crash utility due to missing /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/ folder

Tags: centos, debugging, crash

A CentOS7 server is experiencing crashes.  According to [RHEL7's documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_crash_dump_guide/sect-crash-running-the-utility), I should be able to view details using the crash utility:

```
crash /var/crash/<timestamp>/vmcore /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/<kernel>/vmlinux
```

I see a few folders in /var/crash along with the respective vmcore files.   I am missing is the /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/ folder, which is needed to use `crash`.

What additional utilities are needed so that the modules folder is populated per documentation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous page of the RHEL documentation also tells you following:

> In addition to crash, it is also necessary to install the kernel-debuginfo package that corresponds to your running kernel, which provides the data necessary for dump analysis.

So all you need is to install kernel-debuginfo package with the same version as your kernel.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_crash_dump_guide/chap-analyzing-a-core-dump#sect-crash-installing-the-utility

EDIT:

There is the debuginfo repository:

http://debuginfo.centos.org/7/x86_64/